# How to Debug Karma & Jasmine in Intellij 2016?

Tags: javascript, testing, intellij-idea, jasmine

I got an angular application that I need to unit test/debug.
Running the app works.
Running the tests with Karma & Jasmine from console works.
Running the tests with Karma & Jasmine from Intellij "run Configuration" works.

Putting a breakpoint in my tests and launching tests in debug fails.

I configured the latest Chrome as my test browser, installed JetBrains IDE Support extension, configured ok.

The karma server starts, Starts a new Chrome, which gets detected by the output of the Karma server but nothing else happens. Breakpoints are not hit.

Repeating the same process sometimes (!!) work, without changing anything.

Does someone managed to debug a unit test in karma using Jasmine (Mocha runner would work since it is provided in the default configurations of Intellij, but we use Jasmine here.)

Thanks !